# PHP Switch doesn't return correctly

Tags: php, html, server, php-5.6

For my website I made a form, and one of the form values is for a month they choose.  I have the month return with a value from 1-12, 1 being Jan and 12 being Dec, and I'm having the PHP code below interpret it.

```
switch ($_POST['month']) {
    case '1':
        $GLOBALS['month'] = 'Jan';
        break;
    case '2':
        $GLOBALS['month'] = 'Feb';
        break;
    case '3':
        $GLOBALS['month'] = 'March';
        break;
    case '4':
        $GLOBALS['month'] = 'April';
        break;
    case '5':
        $GLOBALS['month'] = 'May';
        break;
    case '6':
        $GLOBALS['month'] = 'June';
        break;
    case '7':
        $GLOBALS['month'] = 'July';
        break;
    case '8':
        $GLOBALS['month'] = 'Aug';
        break;
    case '9':
        $GLOBALS['month'] = 'Sept';
        break;
    case '10':
        $GLOBALS['month'] = 'Oct';
        break;
    case '11':
        $GLOBALS['month'] = 'Nov';
        break;
    case '12':
        $GLOBALS['month'] = 'Dec';
        break;
    default:
        $GLOBALS['month'] = '';
        break;
};

echo 'month '.$month; //returns "month 12"
```

The issue is that `$month` always returns "12", no matter what the original value is (it doesn't even return "Dec", it just returns "12").  I can't seem to figure out what is wrong with the switch.

**Simplified form**

```
<form action="http://foo.com/foo-redirect/" method="POST" target="_blank">
    <select name="month" required><option value="" disabled selected>Month</option><option value="1">January</option><option value="2">February</option><option value="3">March</option><option value="4">April</option><option value="5">May</option><option value="6">June</option><option value="7">July</option><option value="8">August</option><option value="9">September</option><option value="10">October</option><option value="11">November</option><option value="12">December</option></select>
    <select name="day" required><option value="" disabled selected>Day</option><option value="12">1</option><option value="12">2</option><option value="12">3</option><option value="12">4</option><option value="12">5</option><option value="12">6</option><option value="12">7</option><option value="12">8</option><option value="12">9</option><option value="12">10</option><option value="12">11</option><option value="12">12</option><option value="12">13</option><option value="12">14</option><option value="12">15</option><option value="12">16</option><option value="12">17</option><option value="12">18</option><option value="12">19</option><option value="12">20</option><option value="12">21</option><option value="12">22</option><option value="12">23</option><option value="12">24</option><option value="12">25</option><option value="12">26</option><option value="12">27</option><option value="12">28</option><option value="12">29</option><option value="12">30</option><option value="12">31</option></select>,
    <select name="year" required><option value="" disabled selected>Year</option><option value="2016">2016</option><option value="2017">2017</option></select>
</form>
```

I submitted the form as

Month: 1 (Jan)

Day: 5

Year: 2016

### Update

<del>It is actually a part of the omitted code that had the issue, thank you for the help.</del>

I was incorrect, it actually appears to be a problem with WordPress (I use WordPress to make website changes easier).  Though it says the version is PHP5.6, it lacks some features of PHP5.

Comment: And where do you print the value from the switch statement?

Comment: @Mihai no, I have tried every value (1-12) and they all return "12".

Comment: Your question refers to a variable named `$month`, but there is no `$month` variable in the code you provided.

Comment: @Rizier123 Later in the PHP code, it generates some text with some other values not listed and that are unimportant to this question, but all I use is `echo` with the other values.

Comment: So show us this code. No one will imagine it.

Comment: Before this code, try using `var_dump()` on `$_POST`, and see what the value for `$_POST['month']` is...

Comment: @NateB the `$GLOBALS['month1']` is the variable (as explained here: http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_superglobals.asp )

Comment: @BenPearlKahan `var_dump($_POST['month'])` returns `string(1) “1”` (the value is correct, I used 1 as the form value)

Comment: Your example of code just raises other questions. Where do you echo `$month`? Does this happen in a function or in some other scope? That's why there an [mcve] section of help. Read it.

Comment: @u_mulder in response to Rizier123, I put the code at the end of the PHP code, you may have to scroll down on the PHP code.

Comment: I read this code and it's working correctly, As already said - error is somewhere else. But as we don't see other codes - you'kk have to find out by yourself.

Comment: Does the switch statement resides in a function/method @Jaketr00?

Answer (score 1):

```
$GLOBALS['month'] = '';

switch ($_POST['month']) {
    case '1':
        $GLOBALS['month'] = 'Jan';
        break;
    case '2':
        $GLOBALS['month'] = 'Feb';
        break;
    case '3':
        $GLOBALS['month'] = 'March';
        break;
    case '4':
        $GLOBALS['month'] = 'April';
        break;
    case '5':
        $GLOBALS['month'] = 'May';
        break;
    case '6':
        $GLOBALS['month'] = 'June';
        break;
    case '7':
        $GLOBALS['month'] = 'July';
        break;
    case '8':
        $GLOBALS['month'] = 'Aug';
        break;
    case '9':
        $GLOBALS['month'] = 'Sept';
        break;
    case '10':
        $GLOBALS['month'] = 'Oct';
        break;
    case '11':
        $GLOBALS['month'] = 'Nov';
        break;
    case '12':
        $GLOBALS['month'] = 'Dec';
        break;
    default:
        $GLOBALS['month'] = '';
        break;
};

echo $GLOBALS['month'];
```

Returns correctly the month names.

Your error has to be somewhere later in the code if a print_r of $_POST['month'] at the very beginning of the file returns a value.

1) Check contain of $_POST data.

2) Checking form if $_POST data is missing something.

3) Checking the global var directly after the switch statement end.

**4) If 1 and 3 return data, your error is somewhere later in the code.**

**After your question Update:**

```
$month = $GLOBALS['month'];

echo $month;
```

Should work if you are not editing the value of $GLOBALS['month'] somewhere else.